# Calling Service Lbrary from Web Project - What Goes In Web.Config?

Tags: wcf, web-config, app-config

I am new to WCF and am working on a project 
where I am building a WCF library that is called
by a Web project (ASP.NET 2.03.5 / C#).

I have a few things going on here.

1) I have provided a compliment contract (IJSON) for my 
SOAP contracts (ISOAP) for my JSON web methods.
2) I have one contract, IFileTransferService, that handles
file streaming.

Can you please take a look at my APP.CONFIG and WEB.CONFIG 
files and tell me if they look correct or if I am reproducing
that which is in my App.Config in my Web.Config unnecessarily?
If I am using a Service Library, do I really need to be doing 
things twice (declaring services, bindings, etc)? Does this look 
right?

Also, any other stylistic / constructive comments regarding 
what I have in side system.serviceModel is always appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

WEB.CONFIG

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="MySOAPAuthEP" 
                address="http://localhost:1241/WebProj/auth.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="soapWeb" 
                contract="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.ISOAPAuthService" />
      <endpoint name="MySOAPTradeEP"
                address="http://localhost:1241/WebProj/trade.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="soapWeb" 
                contract="Project.WebAPI.Trade.ISOAPTradeService" />
      <endpoint name="MySOAPFileTransferEP"
                address="http://localhost:1241/WebProj/filetransfer.svc/soap"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="httpLargeDataStream"
                contract="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.ISOAPFileTransferService" />

      <endpoint name="MyJSONAuthEP"
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="jsonWeb"
                contract="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.IJSONAuthService"  />
      <endpoint name="MyJSONTradeEP"
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="jsonWeb"
                contract="Project.WebAPI.Trade.IJSONTradeService"  />
      <endpoint name="MyJSONFileTransferEP"
                binding="webHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="jsonWeb"
                contract="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.IJSONFileTransferService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="soapWeb" />
        <binding name="httpLargeDataStream" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="65536"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Streamed">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonWeb" maxBufferSize="1500000" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="656000" maxArrayLength="656000"
            maxBytesPerRead="656000" maxNameTableCharCount="656000" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpEPBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="BasicHttpEPBehavior" />
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Project.WebAPI.Trade.TradeService">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEPBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyJSONTradeEP" contract="Project.WebAPI.Trade.IJSONTradeService" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MySOAPTradeEP"
          contract="Project.WebAPI.Trade.ISOAPTradeService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1243/WebProj/trade.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.AuthService">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEPBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyJSONAuthEP" contract="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.IJSONAuthService" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MySOAPAuthEP"
          contract="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.ISOAPAuthService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1242/WebProj/auth.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.FileTransferService">

        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEPBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyJSONFileTransferEP" contract="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.IJSONFileTransferService" />

        <endpoint address="soap" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  name="MySOAPFileTransferEP"
                  bindingConfiguration="httpLargeDataStream"
                  contract="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.ISOAPFileTransferService" />

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1244/WebProj/filetransfer.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

APP.CONFIG

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="soapWeb" />
        <binding name="httpLargeDataStream"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 transferMode="Streamed"
                 messageEncoding="Mtom"
                 maxBufferSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonWeb" maxBufferSize="1500000" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="656000" maxArrayLength="656000"
            maxBytesPerRead="656000" maxNameTableCharCount="656000" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Project.WebAPI.Trade.TradeService">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEPBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyJSONTradeEP" contract="Project.WebAPI.Trade.IJSONTradeService" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MySOAPTradeEP"
          contract="Project.WebAPI.Trade.ISOAPTradeService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1243/WebProj/trade.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.AuthService">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEPBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyJSONAuthEP" contract="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.IJSONAuthService" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MySOAPAuthEP"
          contract="Project.WebAPI.Authentication.ISOAPAuthService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1242/WebProj/auth.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.FileTransferService">
        <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpEPBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyJSONFileTransferEP" contract="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.IJSONFileTransferService" />

        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MySOAPFileTransferEP"
                  contract="Project.WebAPI.FileTransfer.ISOAPFileTransferService" />

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1244/WebProj/filetransfer.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpEPBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="BasicHttpEPBehavior" />
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several comments to help declutter your config files and make them more readable:

- you have both the `<services>` as well as the `<client>` sections in your web.config and app.config. Why? This is typically not necessary - the server side (where your server code runs) needs the `<services>`, while the client side that calls the server only needs the `<client>` section
- it appears you've used Visual Studio or svcutil.exe to create your configs, as your binding configuration also lists all the binding defaults (that's the huge plethora of settings you have). You could reduce that to leave just those settings you've actually changed for your specific scenario, thus making the configs much smaller and easier to understand
- do you really need the `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>` setting? This basically "fakes" the HttpContext inside your WCF services so that they look and behave much like ASMX webservices - do you need this?
- this setting here `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />` might be useful and ok in a dev/testing environment, but I would definitely recommend removing it for production
- are you self-hosting, or hosting in IIS? If you're using IIS to host, the defined `<baseAddress>` entry will not be used; in a IIS-hosting environment, the base address is ignored, since the location of the *.svc file (the virtual directory it resides in) is your base address and you can't override that

That's about it at first sight :-)

Marc

Comment: Thanks Marc. I followed your advice and just left the <client> section in my web.config but now can't seem to get it to run. I am getting the following error: Service 'AuthService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element. I recall I had this error when I started out and resolved it by dumping services and bindings in Web.config. Ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Where are you hosting your service class? IIS? Then you need the `<services>` in your web.config, and your `<client>` (but no "services") in the client app.config that accesses that service

Comment: Thanks Again. No, I am self-hosting for development right now.

Comment: I looks like my web.config wants the <services>, <bindings>, and <behaviors> stuff - I can't get it to run otherwise. Works fine once I add everything back in the file. Oh well - if it isn't broken don't fix it, right? Thanks again.